# Python for loop scope when using time.sleep(random)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im currently having a bit of difficulty figuring out why my time.sleep(r) function below is not generating a new random time after every time it runs.

```
    r = random.uniform(5, 15)

for filename in os.listdir(r'NewImages'):
    base = os.path.basename(r'NewImages//' + filename)
    os.path.splitext(base)
    caption = os.path.splitext(base)[0]
    # graph.put_photo(image=open(post_filepath + '\\' + filename, 'rb'), message=caption)
    print(filename, caption)
    print('waiting ' + str(r))
    time.sleep(r)
```

post()

Comment: If you roll a die once and look at it five times, you're not going to get five different numbers. You need to roll it every time.

Comment: `sleep` does not produce random numbers.  How did you expect `r` to change, when you did not change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like how @user2357112supportsMonica explained it, you need to roll it everytime. I would suggest you do this:

`time.sleep(random.uniform(5, 15))`

or:

`time.sleep(random.randInt(5, 15))`

as it calls the command directly, having no need to create a variable for the random number.

But please do comment if there's a problem with it.

Answer (score 1):

if i am correct then you want a random number generated for time to sleep

the you can use something like this:

```
import random

random_number_sleep = random.randint(5, 15)

time.sleep(random_number_sleep)
```

please let me know if i took it wrong